# Collection with generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections

I have a question about using generics with collections.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

We know that the above line means that `ArrayList` `al` is restricted to hold only integers. So the following line gives a compilation error:

```
al.add("wwww");
```

But I don't understand what the below line means,

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Where we don't give `ArrayList<Integer>` at the left side while declaring. Now the following line *doesn't* give a compilation error:

```
al.add("wwww");
```

So if I declare like

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

that means `a1` can accept any types?

What's the difference between those two declarations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this code:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a1.add("www");
```

the compiler will generate a warning (which you should heed!) but the code will run without error. The problem comes on extracting data from `a1`. If you "know" that it contains `Integer` values, you can just do this:

```
Integer val = (Integer) a1.get(index);
```

But when you hit the `"www"` element you're going to get a `ClassCastException`. Generics are meant to move such errors to compile time instead of forcing the poor developer to track down how a `String` value ended up in that `Integer` array list.

Answer (score 9):

The latter declaration (without generic type) is obsolete and deprecated. You shouldn't use it, it compiles only for backward compatibility. Modern IDEs will generate warning here.

Also note that Java only enforces generic types at compile time, so technically you can add incorrect type to a collection with some extra casts. That's why it is better to stay with generics all the time and do not bypass them.

Comment: ...and your IDE (if you are using one) probably shows a warning for it.

Comment: @Axel: +1. Independently I added the same comment to my answer, you must believe me ;-).

Comment: For some reason as of 7 the netbeans people disabled showing standard javac warnings by default.  (and a significant increase in telling interns "fix your raw type warnings.")

Comment: It's not just for backward compatibility that it compiles. A lot of the collections framework would be impossible to write in Java (without JNI) unless such things did compile.

Comment: @TedHopp - That's interesting. So there are situations where raw types are still necessary (rather than using wildcards for example)?

Comment: @PaulBellora There's an interesting discussion of issues with generics in [this paper](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html) by Brian Goetz.

Answer (score 0):

The latter declaration is basicly the same as:

```
ArrayList<Object> al=new ArrayList<Object>();
```

thus accepting any Object. It should not be used, and it is possible to use so that Java is backward compatible (pre Java1.5).

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this `ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();` to avoid adding to your list objects with another types because you'll see the error compile time. Of course you can use `ArrayList al=new ArrayList<Integer>();` but then you must be careful. In another words, always use the first one :D

Answer (score 0):

Generics are implemented by type erasure: generic type information is present only at compile time, after which it is erased by the compiler. So, ArrayList al declaration let compiler accept any type. Here is [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of declaration is allowed for backward compability. So you can for example pass you generic list to the method from old-style library wich accepts only raw list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
OldStyledClass.method(myArray);
```

where method is declared like:

```
public static void method(List list)...
```

In this case you have some special utility methods in java.util.Collections. So you can pass to this method protected list:

```
OldStyledClass.method(Collections.checkedList(myArray, Integer.class));
```

If method will try to put into your list object of some other type you will get ClassCastException immediatley.